# How to detect new print jobs in Windows queue using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way, using PowerShell, to detect when a new print job arrives in a print queue. Have been searching for the past couple of days and the best I've come up with is reference to a "PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB" flag [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541273.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but nothing about how to use it.

I would like to be able to do something like threads that talk about registering for an event to watch for new files in a folder (e.g. [this TechNet article](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b) using System.IO.FileSystemWatcher).

Is there something comparable for print queues? Any example code, or even pointers to articles or tutorials, would be greatly appreciated. I've only started into PowerShell a couple of months ago.

Comment: While not exactly what I was looking for, hence my not offering it as an "Answer", this is pretty close:

 - enable Event logging on "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational" log
 - right click on the event of interest (e.g. EventID 309, which is, essentially, "Finished spooling print job") and select "Attach Task To This Event..."
 - create a PS script to respond to this event. See [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/)

Note that I haven't actually tried this yet either.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a print server then you can use the PowerShell PrintManagment Module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/?view=win10-ps.

Regards
Shihan

Comment: Thanks, Shihan but unless I'm missing something, none of the commandlets in this module notifies me of new print jobs. I can use Get-PrintJob in a loop to poll but that's not what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware i dont think there is any built in PowerShell cmdlets to get what you want. but you can script it either using the Get-PrintJob Module or you can use WMI to get this information. If you want to be notified you can either write to the event log or pipe the output out to send-mailmessage and send you a email notification when a print job is in error.

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue |Select Name, @{Expression={$_.jobs};Label="CurrentJobs"}, TotalJobsPrinted, JobErrors
```